# By using spring framework how to design a web page which shows videos to the user

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

We are developing a web application in which we have to show list of videos to the user so facing issues with chrome has it is not allowing video forward so please suggest us with better solution for it

controller code

```java
@RequestMapping(value="GetVideo.ht", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void getImage(@RequestParam("video_name") String name,
    HttpServletResponse response,
    HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("I am from GetVideo.ht");

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    // response.setContentType("video/mp4");
    headers.set("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
    headers.set("Content-Range", "bytes=0-1025/9044858");
    headers.set("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
    headers.set("Content-Length", "9044858");

    String decrypt = Enc.DecryptText(name);
    System.out.println("decry=" + decrypt);
    File imageFile = new File(decrypt);
    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + imageFile.getName().replace(" ", "_"));

    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
    IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream()); 
    in.close();
}
```

in jsp page

```html
<c:forEach items="${user_videos}" var="v" varStatus="status">
  <div id="${status.index}" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center pt-4">
      <video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="670" height="400" 
        controls id="vid${v.video_id}" onplay="loadVideo(${v.video_id},${status.index})">
        <source src="GetVideo.ht?video_name=${v.uploaded_video}" 
                type="video/mp4" >
      </video>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller would need to support byte-range requests.  But why don't you use [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) for the video content portion of your solution?  That way you won't need to implement any of the video content-handling you have presented above.  Spring Content will provide this for you.

To add Spring Content to your project:

> pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
    <artifactId>content-fs-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Associate content with a Video entity (for example).

> Video.java

```
@Entity
public class Video {
   ...

   @ContentId
   private String contentId;

   @ContentLength
   private Long contentLength;

   @MimeType
   private String mimeType;

   ...
```

> VideoLibrary.java

Create a `VideoLibrary` interface.

```
  @StoreRestResource(path="videos")
  public interface VideoLibrary extends ContentStore<Video,String> {
    //
  }
```

Tie it all together by `@EnableFilesystemStores` and giving your video library a "persistent folder".  This is where uploaded videos will be uploaded to and streamed from.

> SpringBootApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class YourSpringBootApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(YourSpringBootApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Configuration
  @EnableFilesystemStores
  public static class StoreConfig {
    File videoLibrary() {
        return new File("/path/to/your/videos");
    }

    @Bean
    public FileSystemResourceLoader fsResourceLoader() throws Exception {
      return new FileSystemResourceLoader(videoLibary().getAbsolutePath());
    }
  }

}
```

This is all you need to create a REST-based video library service at `/videos`.  Essentially, when your application starts, Spring Content will look at your dependencies (seeing Spring Content FS/REST), look at your `VideoLibrary` interface and inject an implementation of that interface for on the filesystem.  It will also inject a `Controller` that forwards http requests to that implementation as well.  This saves you having to implement any of this yourself.

So...

`POST /videos/{video-entity-id}`

with a multipart/form-data request will store the video in `/path/to/your/videos` and associate it with the video entity whose id is `video-entity-id`.

`GET /videos/{video-entity-id}`

will fetch it again.  This supports partial byte ranges requests; i.e. the video streaming that you need.

and so on...support full CRUD.

You would just need to update your HTML to call the correct URI:

```
<c:forEach items="${user_videos}" var="v" varStatus="status">
  <div id="${status.index}" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center pt-4">
      <video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="670" height="400" 
        controls id="vid${v.video_id}">
        <source src="/videos/${v.uploaded_video}" type="video/mp4" >
      </video>
</c:forEach>
```

There are a couple of getting started guides [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  The  reference guide is [here](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/refs/release/fs-index.html).  And there is a tutorial video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbDaONWWT3s).  The coding bit starts about 1/2 way through.

HTH